# PDO inserts an id as 0 for some reason

Tags: php, pdo

So I wrote this method, for my chrome plugin (which does an ajax request to run this method), and when it runs, `file_put_contents` shows an id of what ever was inserted, but then when it gets to the `insert ignore into songs`, it puts in `0` for the `artist_id`. I have no idea why... Can someone help my find the part where I am going wrong?

```
<?php
public function saveLyrics($artist, $title, $lyric){
    $this->db->query("insert ignore into artists (artist_name) value (:artist)", array("artist"   => $artist));
    $artist_id = (int)$this->db->insertID();
    file_put_contents(__DIR__ . "/../process/page", "artist id: $artist_id");
    //return;
    if($artist_id == 0){
        $artist_id = (int)$this->db->getOne("select artist_id from artists where artist_name = :artist", array("artist" => $artist));
    }
    if($artist_id == 0){
        return false;
    }
    $this->db->query("insert ignore into songs (artist_id, song_name) values (:aid, :title)", array("aid"    => $artist_id, "title"  => $title));
    $song_id = (int)$this->db->insertID();
    if($song_id == 0){
        $song_id = (int)$this->db->getOne("select song_id from songs where artist_id = aid and song_name = :title", array("aid"   => $artist_id, "title" => $title));
    }
}
```

PDO Wrapper:

```
<?php

/** 
 * @property PDO $pdo Description
 * @property PDOStatement $sql Description
 */
class DB{

    protected $sql = null;
    protected $pdo = null;

    public function connect(){
        $this->pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname=envne;host=xxx", "xxx", "xxx");
    }

    public function query($query, $params = array()){
        if($this->pdo === null){
            $this->connect();
        }
        $this->sql = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
        foreach($params as $key => $value){
            $this->sql->bindParam($key, $value);
        }
        $this->sql->execute();
        if(!$this->sql)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
    public function insertID(){
        return (int)$this->pdo->lastInsertId();
    }

    public function getAll($query, $params = array()){
        $this->query($query, $params);
        return $this->sql->fetchAll();
    }

    public function getOne($query, $params = array()){
        $this->query($query, $params);
        return $this->sql->fetchColumn();
    }

}
```

Artists:

```
mysql> describe artists;
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| artist_id   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| artist_name | char(50)         | YES  | UNI | NULL              |                |
| add_date    | timestamp        | YES  |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Songs:

```
mysql> describe songs;
+------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| song_id    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| artist_id  | int(11) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                |
| album_id   | int(11)          | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                |
| song_name  | char(50)         | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| track_id   | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| date_added | timestamp        | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: Do you have an `auto_increment` column in the table? Is the insert being ignored because of a duplicate key?

Comment: Table definition please

Comment: Sorry, I meant `artist_id` not `song_id`.

Comment: So, everything there seems to check out. Is `db` a class you made or a framework? If the former I would guess that the error is there.

Comment: DB is a pdo wrapper. I'll post the code.

Comment: Insert ignore returns 0 for last-insert-id

Comment: @hjpotter92 then why was I getting a number in my `file_put_contents`?

Comment: @hjpotter92 even so, it shouldn't be inserting into songs, because my second if statement should catch it.

Comment: Use an `echo` for `artist_id` before inserting it into `songs` table.

Comment: Would not having `PDO::PARAM_INT` cause this problem? I wouldn't think so, but could it: `$this->sql->bindParam($key, $value, PDO::PARAM_INT);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just decided to put the Id directly into the query, and that works.

```
$artist_id = (int)$this->db->insertID();
$this->db->query("insert ignore into songs (artist_id, song_name) values ($artist_id, :title)", array("title"  => $title));
```

Another way that works is using a question mark instead

```
$artist_id = (int)$this->db->insertID();
$this->db->query("insert ignore into songs (artist_id, song_name) values (?, ?)", array($artist_id, $title));
```

Comment: Hm Maybe works, but it is absolutely not good practice. You are missing the point of binding parameters to querys.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem : new inserted items get an id of 0 even though the `ID` field is set to `AUTO_INCRIMENT`.

The solution I found is very similar to yours. Using your code this is what we get :

```
$this->db->query("insert ignore into songs (artist_id, song_name) values (LAST_INSERT_ID(), :title)", array("title"  => $title));
```

As you can see, I replaced `$artist_id = (int)$this->db->insertID();` and `$artist_id` with SQL function `LAST_INSERT_ID()`.

I hope this can help someone someday :)

Answer (score -1):

You're placeholders are incorrectly defined: (You're missing the colons)
I would do something like this:

```
public function saveLyrics($artist, $title, $lyric){
    $this->db->query("insert ignore into artists (artist_name) value (:artist)", array(":artist"   => $artist));
    $artist_id = (int)$this->db->insertID();
    file_put_contents(__DIR__ . "/../process/page", "artist id: $artist_id");
    //return;
    if($artist_id == 0){
        $artist_id = (int)$this->db->getOne("select artist_id from artists where artist_name = :artist", array(":artist" => $artist));
        return false;
    }
    $this->db->query("insert ignore into songs (artist_id, song_name) values (:aid, :title)", array(":aid"=>$artist_id, ":title"=>$title));
    $song_id = (int)$this->db->insertID();
    if($song_id == 0){
        $song_id = (int)$this->db->getOne("select song_id from songs where artist_id = :aid and song_name = :title", array(":aid"=>$artist_id, ":title"=>$title));
    }
}
```

Taking a look at your PDO-wrapper you have this code:

```
if(!$this->sql)
    return false;
```

Because of this you would never notice an actual error. I guess the error is about the placeholder in this case.
(If `$this->db->query("insert ignore into songs (...` fails $song_id would just be false if there is an error when executing the query).

Use exceptions instead and catch the errors, that would be better.

I also noticed that:

```
$song_id = (int)$this->db->insertID();
```

would cast the value twice, first in above code and then in the actual function insertID() in the PDO-Wrapper. Maybe this is an issue also to consider.